# parallelogramm law and inner products

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the sum of two norms $||.||_1=\sqrt{(.,.)_1}$ and  $||.||_2=\sqrt{(.,.)_2}$, where $(.,.)_1$ and $(.,.)_2$ are the quadratic forms of inner products on a normed linear space, again produced by an inner product on that space, i.e. does it obey the parallelogramm law, too? There is a simple counterexample for seminorms.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, now there is a simple counterexample for seminorms $||\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{array}
\right)||_1=|x_1|$ and $||\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{array}
\right)||_2=|x_2|$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$, so it can´t be proven in this straightforward way, if at all, I tried to find a counterexample, as well considering different norms on $C^2(I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x) = \alpha_1\|x\|_1 + \alpha_2\|x\|_2$ for some scalars $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 > 0$.
It should be clear that $f$ defines a norm. Now show that $f$ satisfies the parallelogram law. It should be straightforward to do so, but let me know if you need any help.